# Update or Reload Store of ExtJs ComboBox

Tags: extjs

I'd like to know a way of how to update or reload the list values of a ExtJs ComboBox. For instance, I have a some checkboxes. These checkboxes determine what values the ComboBox should have. So, after selecting some of those, I click the drowndown list (combobox) to see the values.

In short, how can I change the values (store) of a ComboBox already has.

Hope someone can help me

Thanks

Comment: Did some answer solved your problem? Accept the best answer clicking on the check-mark, please.

Answer (score 14):

I've been using this undocumented ExtJs API function to change the store at runtime:

```
mycombobox.bindStore(newStore);
```

as stated by the support team in http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?40749-Change-Combobox-store-data-update.

Edit: If I want to put the new data when the store is populated, I do something like this

```
storeMyStore = new Ext.data.Store({
    ...
    listeners: {
        load: function(this, records, options) {
            cbMyCombo.bindStore( storeMyStore );
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Not very "undocumented" actually, 
http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.5/#!/api/Ext.form.field.ComboBox-method-bindStore

but did the trick for me, thanks!

Comment: Oh, well, it was undocumented on 2011 :)

Answer (score 7):

It goes a little something like this

```
{
  xtype: 'checkbox',
  //configs
  listeners : {
     checked : function (checkbox, checkedBool) {
         var yourCombo = Ext.getCmp(yourComboID);

         //I'm not sure what params you will need to reload the comboBox from your
         // service but hopfully this will give the jist of things. . .

         yourCombo.store.reload(
                  {   
                     params: 
                         {yourParam : checkedBool},
                         {yourRowID : rowID}
                    });
      }
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

Here I making a combobox that is updated after a selection is made on another ComboBox.
Basically, the final user can use the two comboboxes to select a main category and a sub-category, which is based on the selection made on the first combobox.

This is the store for First comboBox:

```
Ext.define("StoreSubject", {
extend: "Ext.data.Model",
fields: [
{
    name: 'i_Id'
},
{
    name: 's_Value'
}
]
});

var StoreSubject = Ext.create('Ext.data.JsonStore', {
model: 'StoreSubject',
proxy: {

    type: 'ajax',
    url: '../General/AdministrationDefaultXMLDOM.aspx?qid=15',
    reader: {
        type: 'json'
    }
}
});
StoreSubject.load();
```

This is the store for Second comboBox:

```
Ext.define("StoreLanguageGroup", {
extend: "Ext.data.Model",
fields: [
{
    name: 'i_Id'
},
{
    name: 's_Value'
}
]
});
var StoreLanguageGroup = Ext.create('Ext.data.JsonStore', {
model: 'StoreLanguageGroup',
proxy: {

    type: 'ajax',
    url: '../General/AdministrationDefaultXMLDOM.aspx?qid=16',
    reader: {
        type: 'json'
    }
}
});
```

My code for Comobox is looks like this..

First ComboBox :

```
var cmbSubjectName = Ext.create('Ext.form.field.ComboBox', {
id: 'cmbSubjectName',
fieldLabel: '<b>Subject</b>',
name: 'cmbSubjectName',
valueField: 's_Value',
displayField: 's_Value',
allowBlank: false,
anchor: '80%',
labelWidth: 150,
emptyText: '[--Choose--]',
minChars: 0,
store: StoreSubject,
queryMode: 'local',
typeAhead: true,
listeners: {
    'select': {
        fn: function (combo, value) {
            var strSubjectName = Ext.getCmp('cmbSubjectName').getValue();
            Ext.getCmp('cmbLanguageType').clearValue();
            Ext.getCmp('cmbLanguageType').getStore().load({
                params: {
                    SubjectName: strSubjectName
                }
            });
        }
    }

},
});
```

This code is used to call and override the combox store (Impotent otherwise it will keep on loading )

```
Ext.override(Ext.LoadMask, {
onHide: function () {
    this.callParent();
}
});
```

//---------------------------

Second ComboBox :

```
var cmbLanguageType = Ext.create('Ext.form.field.ComboBox', {
id: 'cmbLanguageType',
fieldLabel: '<b>Language</b>',
multipleSelect: false,
name: 'cmbLanguageType',
valueField: 's_Value',
displayField: 's_Value',
allowBlank: false,
anchor: '80%',
labelWidth: 150,
emptyText: '[--Choose--]',
minChars: 0,
store: StoreLanguageGroup,
queryMode: 'local',
typeAhead: true,
});
```

Hope this will helps you.. and Please rate my answer

Comment: Welcome to [so]! Please take a [tour].

Answer (score 0):

In an event listener on the checkboxes, get a reference to the store that your ComboBox is reading from.  Then invoke its add or remove functions to update the data in the store based on what check box is [checked](http://extjs-public.googlecode.com/svn-history/r110/extjs-3.x/release/docs/index.html.)  Once the updates are complete, invoke a `doLayout()` on the ComboBox component, it should re-render itself based on the current state of the store.

Although I think there is a way to have it automatically update any time the store updates -- I haven't used that yet.

Comment: Do you think it is possible to update the combobox inside of one of its events? For example, I want to click the combobox (the down arrow), then before it displays, a function get the values based on the selected checkboxes.

Comment: Actually, I have a gridPanel with checkboxes. I am getting some values from records obtained by getSelections. I'd like to find a way to do this process once instead of doing it each time I select a row (or select the checkbox). That is why I got the idea of doing it by clicking the ComboBox.

Comment: It's definitely possible to do it inside the combobox's internal events, extend the ComboBox object and add your own js before calling the parent's event handler.  As to the gridPanel, it's a bit hard to conceptualize without the code.